# Exception when trying to send an array via php webservice

Tags: java, php, arrays, web-services, wsdl

When I'm trying to get an array object on the Android client side I get this error:

```
org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: START_TAG {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope (position:START_TAG (empty) <br>@1:7 in java.io.InputStreamReader@415f48e0)
```

I read some of the answers here for that problem and they say its because the parameters like name space or url or soap command were wrong. This is not the case.

I am trying to build a PHP web service using nusoap and calling one of the methods. The method is supposed to return an array:

```
function GetAllWorkerUsers($id,$Password)
{
     $ret_array=array();
     $person=new Person( 12, 11, 11, "First", "Last", true, "12345", 0);
     array_push($ret_array, $person->GetWsdlObj()); 
     return $ret_array;
}
```

The Person class:

```
class WorkerUser
{
    public $id;
    public $id2;
    public $id3;
    public $name1;
    public $name2;
    public $somebool;
    public $name3;
    public $id4;


    function __construct($id, $id2, $id3, $name1, $name2, $somebool, $name3, $id4) 
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->id2= $id2;
        $this->id3= $id3;
        $this->name1= $name1;
        $this->name2= $name2;
        $this->somebool= $somebool;
        $this->name3= $name3;
         $this->id4= $id4;
    }

    function GetWsdlObj()
    {
        $obj['id']= $this->id;
        $obj['id2']=$this->id2;
        $obj['id3']=$this->id3;
        $obj['name1']=$this->name1;
        $obj['name2']= $this->name2;
        $obj['somebool']=$this->somebool;
        $obj['name3']=$this->name3;
        $obj['id4']=$this->id4;
        return $obj;
    }
}
```

The problem happens when trying to return an array with that person object inside. When I do that, I get on the client side the exception above. 
If I'm trying to return null, it works without exception. If I'm trying to return the array without pushing the person object inside, I get an empty array without any exception. I tried changing the method to return only an object of type `Person` not in an array and it also works. Only when trying to return an array with an object inside I get the exception. Do you perhaps see why?

Comment: So do you get the exception *after* you return the array or when you initialize the object? Can you var_dump `$person` and `$ret_array`?

Comment: It looks like you're outputting whitespace / <br/> before the object. (mind you this is just a quick look). See if you can get the output you send in a browser and check the source. could be you have whitespace/newline in your php receiving script which gets replaced to <br /> or something similar.

Comment: @vanamerongen the exception happens after i return the array. There isn't any problem with the array initializing or in the object creation or in the pushing of the object to the array (checked it with in the server side with a try catch).

Comment: @Joeblade I'm not using a special script.. it's just using a nusoap object which i can register the methods and types to it. then I'm auto generating some java classes out of it which implements the service class in the java side and i simply call the methods in that service

Comment: @YonatanNir fair enough. I thought perhaps in the php script that is called by your generated java class, there may be some additional characters, before the php object is serialized, which might cause this issue. but it was a guess (hence comment, not answer :D). I would recommend checking the content of the serialized object in a browser or in your debugger to see. It really looks like the parser is complaining about finding a <br> tag in the serialized content

Comment: @Joeblade not sure if it helps but i tried it now and i can get without a problem a person object not in an array. it seems to happen only when sending an array with the object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem. I used Visual Studio to add the service to a new sln and there I managed to find a way to view the SOAP message that was returned from the web service.
It seemed that there was a warning in the `nusoap.php` file. in the current version it was in line 6132:

`$this->debug("serializing array element: $k, $v of type: $typeDef[arrayType]");`

This warning was added to the returned SOAP message for some reason and that made the parser not recognize the content of the message. After I commented out the line, the problem was fixed.